# How to write to Redux store outside of a React component?

Tags: react-native, redux, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a React Native app where I am using HeadlessJS to call a handler on receipt of a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification.

Inside my handler which is a function, not a React component, I am accessing the Redux store using the following method:

```js
import store from '../redux/store';

const backgroundNotificationHandler = async message => {

  const state = store.getState();
...
```

My question is, how can I update the store in a a way that isn't a 'hack'?

Currently I have the following line in the function:

`state.user.wokenFromBackgroundListener = true;`

Surprisingly is works, but this is without dispatching an action or using a reducer.

Is there a better way to do it?

I can't dispatch an action because the function is not a component and it is not a component because it can't be - it requires a function as in the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.5/headless-js-android).

My code in index.js is:

```js
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(backgroundNotificationHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatching from component props is just an added functionality provided by [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate). You can still use plain redux api, in this case you can dispatch to store using [store.dispatch](https://redux.js.org/api/store/#dispatchaction)

```
store.dispatch({ type: 'SOME_ACTION', payload: [1,2,3] })
```

However I'm not sure if you should be doing that, I haven't used HeadlessJS myself but I would first check and make sure that these task handlers are actually being run in the same context your app is running (e.g. confirm that they share store instance with your app, and NOT create a separate store just because you import store in file with the handler)

Comment: Ok thanks very much for pointing that out! I will try it out. In the meantime, what's the best way to check that the store's not being duplicated? If I log / look at the store in the app and the handler, should they eventually be different if they are? The handler is not wrapped in the provider

Comment: the easiest would be to change store state from the app and read it from the handler. Or dispatch an action from the handler and see if it affects components in the app. Wrapping in provider doesn’t matter (you actually can’t even wrap it in provider since there is no react in handler) - just store.dispatch is perfectly fine